# Handle aggregate promise of EachPromise (each_limit) in Guzzle

Tags: php, pagination, promise, guzzle, guzzle6

## The task

Suppose we have an API POST endpoint which returns answer like this:

```
{
  "data": [1,2,3],
  "total_rows": 20
}
```

Which means that we received data partially, only the first page of 3 entries. The total entries count is 20, which means we want to call other pages using some offset in request. The total count (and possibly offset) is therefore only known after the first call is completed, while other calls do not depend on each other and can be done simultaneously.

## The Toolset

It's PHP and for this task Guzzle 6 is used with Promises/A+. Additionally, Guzzle offers EachPromise class, which receives an iterable of multiple promises and a config hash to setup processing. As per PhpDoc block of that class constructor:

> Configuration hash can include the following key value pairs:
>
> - fulfilled: (callable) Invoked when a promise fulfills. The function   is invoked with three arguments: the fulfillment value, the index
>     position from the iterable list of the promise, and the aggregate
>     promise that manages all of the promises. The aggregate promise may
>     be resolved from within the callback to short-circuit the promise.
> - rejected: (callable) Invoked when a promise is rejected. The   function is invoked with three arguments: the rejection reason, the
>     index position from the iterable list of the promise, and the
>     aggregate promise that manages all of the promises. The aggregate
>     promise may be resolved from within the callback to short-circuit
>     the promise.
> - concurrency: (integer) Pass this configuration option to limit the   allowed number of outstanding concurrently executing promises,
>     creating a capped pool of promises. There is no limit by default.

## The code

```php
$paginatedResult = $this->client->sendAsync($this->createRequest($requestBody))
    ->then(function (ResponseInterface $response) use ($requestBody) {
            return $this->deserializeToPaginatedResult(
                $response,
                $requestBody->paginatedResultClass()
            );
        }
    )->wait();

$pageGenerator = function () use ($paginatedResult, $requestBody) {
    $perPageCount = count($paginatedResult->getItems());
    $totalItems = $paginatedResult->getTotalCount();

    for ($currentOffset = $perPageCount; $currentOffset <= $totalItems; $currentOffset += $perPageCount) {
        $newRequestBody = clone $requestBody;
        $newRequestBody->setOffset($currentOffset);

        yield $this->client->sendAsync($this->createRequest($newRequestBody));
    }
};

$aggregatedResult = (new EachPromise(
    $pageGenerator(), [
        'concurrency' => 4,
        'fulfilled' => function ($promiseResult, $promiseIndex, $promiseAggregate) use ($requestBody) {
            $paginatedResult = $this->deserializeToPaginatedResult(
                $promiseResult,
                $requestBody->paginatedResultClass()
            );

            return $paginatedResult->getItems();
        },
    ]
))->promise()
    ->then(
        function ($promisedAggregatedResult) {
            var_dump($promisedAggregatedResult);
        }
    )
    ->wait();

var_dump($aggregatedResult);
```

## The problem

In the config hash the `fulfilled` callback receives 3 objects, as documentation states. The `$promiseResult` can be properly handled and `$paginatedResult->getItems()` actually returns an array of items in requested page, but I cannot aggregate those items. The `$aggregatedResult` is `null`, and the `$promisedAggregatedResult` inside the last *then*ed fulfillment callback is also `null`.

## The question

How should one properly use Guzzle's `EachPromise` (and it's helper functions `each` and `each_limit`) to aggregate results of all the promises passed to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The reason

As per EachPromise class description:

> Represents a promise that iterates over many promises and invokes
> side-effect functions in the process.

So those config hash callables are just **side-effect** functions which **might** or **might not** short-circuit resolve the aggregate promise. And that's exactly is the reason why `fulfillment` function neither affected the `$promiseAggregate`, nor ended up in last *then* fulfillment callable argument `$promisedAggregatedResult`.

The hint on proper usage can be found in `\GuzzleHttp\Promise\all` and `\GuzzleHttp\Promise\some` functions. The key idea is to `use` external aggregate by reference in those side-effect `fulfilled`/`rejected` callbacks. If the aggregate promise is never resolved inside those side-effect function, then it resolves to `null`, which is then passed on in the next `then` fulfillment callback. Again, one should `use` aggregate by reference in the fulfillment callable just to return it as promise fulfillment value.

### The actual code solution

```php
$paginatedResult = $this->client->sendAsync($this->createRequest($requestBody))
    ->then(function (ResponseInterface $response) use ($requestBody) {
            return $this->deserializeToPaginatedResult(
                $response,
                $requestBody->paginatedResultClass()
            );
        }
    )->wait();

$pageGenerator = function () use ($paginatedResult, $requestBody) {
    $perPageCount = count($paginatedResult->getItems());
    $totalItems = $paginatedResult->getTotalCount();

    for ($currentOffset = $perPageCount; $currentOffset <= $totalItems; $currentOffset += $perPageCount) {
        $newRequestBody = clone $requestBody;
        $newRequestBody->setOffset($currentOffset);

        yield $this->client->sendAsync($this->createRequest($newRequestBody));
    }
};
$items = $paginatedResult->getItems();

return each_limit(
    $pageGenerator(),
    4,
    function ($promiseResult) use (&$items, $requestBody) {
        $paginatedResult = $this->deserializeToPaginatedResult(
            $promiseResult,
            $requestBody->paginatedResultClass()
        );
        $items = array_merge($items, $paginatedResult->getItems());
    },
    function ($reason, $idx, PromiseInterface $aggregate) {
        $aggregate->reject($reason);
    })->then(function () use (&$items) {
        ksort($items);
        return $items;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Pool::batch()` method for that, it does almost the same inside.

```
$pageGenerator = function () use (...) {
    // ...
    yield $this->createRequest($newRequestBody);
    // ...
}

$responses = Pool::batch($this->client, $pageGenerator(), ['concurrency' => 4]);
```